# How to properly configure a React project with TypeScript to be used as a module?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a module and an app made in react with typescript. I want to import a component from the module into the app, but it seems that the app doesn't recognize the the module is made in typescript. I'm getting the following error:

```js
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 12:35-41
export 'default' (imported as 'Header') was not found in 'test-module' (possible exports: Header)

ERROR in ./node_modules/test-module/src/components/Header.tsx 3:0
Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (3:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react';
| 
> interface HeaderProps {
|   name: string;
|   children?: ReactElement;

ERROR in src/App.tsx:3:8
TS2613: Module '"/react/test-app/node_modules/test-module/index"' has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { Header } from "/react/test-app/node_modules/test-module/index"' instead?
    1 | import React from 'react';
    2 | import './App.css';
  > 3 | import Header from 'test-module';
      |        ^^^^^^
    4 | //import Header from './components/Header';
    5 |
    6 | function App() {
```

I added an index.ts file to the root of the module with the following configuration:

```js
export { default as Header } from './src/components/Header';
```

The package.json file of the module has the following:

```json
"main": "index.ts",
```

I don't understand why it says it doesn't have a default export when I apparently added one.

If I copy the component directly from the module into the app, it works correctly, as you can see in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu4_gdXTDb8

Do you know what I might be missing to properly import the module into the app?

I'm leaving the code for the module here: https://github.com/sgb004/react-typescript-module-test in case you want to review the package.json configuration in more detail. I'm also leaving the code for the app here: https://github.com/sgb004/react-typescript-app-test, in case you want to recreate the error.

Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
export { default as Header } from './src/components/Header';
```

Is the same as

```
import Header from './src/components/Header';
export Header
```

The error is clear about it `export 'default' (imported as 'Header') was not found` - there is no export named `default`

Then it list possible exports `possible exports: Header`

So either import it using

```
import { Header } from 'test-module';
```

Or change the export code to:

```
export { default } from './src/components/Header';
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! :D, now I only have the error: ERROR in ./node_modules/test-module/src/components/Header.tsx 3:0
Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (3:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react';
| 
> interface HeaderProps {
|  name: string;
|  children?: ReactElement;